# run a bash script at logoff, shutdown, and restart on Linux

Tags: linux, shell-script, linux-distributions, window-manager, desktop-environments

I need to run a bash script each time a Debian-esque thick client logs off, shuts down, or restarts. Outside of that, it can be any distro, desktop environment, window manager, or otherwise (preferably not Unity or Gnome 3; these are older machines), so long as it can do what I need.

I have already tried Lubuntu 12.04, without any luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to look into run levels, and how upstart ties in with them. This [page](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#system-phases) explains a lot about two of the three stages you are interested in, shutdown and reboot, log off should also just be a simple hook.

Comment: _"log off should also just be a simple hook"_ can you expand on that? What do you mean hook, exactly? I knew about run levels relating to shutdown and reboot, but I did not think that logging off was a different run level.

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to state that it wasn't necessarily a change in run levels, you might be able to trigger off an event from a job stopping.. or from a custom triggered upstart instance for your user : http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#upstart-user-sessions-spec

Comment: I see. If I trigger from an event stopping, how would my script be guaranteed to execute before it gets stopped?

Comment: If you use the Method Event, you can give your script parameters, as they say on that page: "`The caller waits for the work to be done, and if problems were encountered, it expects to be informed of this fact.`".

Comment: Alright, Thanks. If I have more questions I'll post a second question, as im getting away from the original.

Comment: Yeah, it's a seriously large concept, which is why I really didn't try to get into too much detail :)